# R - grouping (clustering) time series data

Tags: r, time-series, clustering

I have some dummy time series data of transaction of different individuals in 2009:

`> str(sample_matrix_p)`

`Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':  1212 obs. of  3 variables:`

`$ obj_id     : chr  "aflg182184" "aflg182184" "aflg182184" "aflg182184" ...`

`$ date       : chr  "2009-01" "2009-02" "2009-03" "2009-04" ...`

`$ transaction: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...`

`obj_id` is the individual id
`date` is from 2009 Jan to Dec
`transaction` is the count of transactions in that month

Now I want to group or cluster the individuals by their transaction movement(trend, change, etc.) throughout the year 2009, is there any recommended algorithms and sample codes that work for such kind of data?

[image: 2009 line stack chart]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use hierarchical clustering or k-means.

1) Compute the transaction movement feature you want to use for clustering.

2) Spread your dataset so as to have date as column names (2009-01, 2009-02... ) and as values the computed feature. You may check the function `spread` from `tidyr` package. It should be something like:

```
sample_matrix_p_transormed <- spread(sample_matrix_p_updated_new_feature, key = date, value = transaction_feature)
```

You should have the columns: obj_id and dates (each date corresponds to one column)

3) Use hierarchical clustering or k-means on the "dates" columns.

Example hierarchical clustering:

```
distance <- dist(sample_matrix_p_transormed %>% select(-obj_id)) # the default method is euclidean distance

hclustering <- hclust(distance, method = "average") # check out the different methods in the documentation

plot(hclustering) # or make a dendrogram with as.dendrogram

split_cl <- cutree(hclustering, h = give_a_value_based_on_plot_analysis_and_business_context)

sample_matrix_p_transormed <- sample_matrix_p_transormed %>% mutate(cluster = split_cl) # add cluster value

gathered_data <- gather(sample_matrix_p_transormed, key = date, value = transaction_feature, -obj_id, -cluster) # get back the data in tidy format
```

Comment: See also the blog post https://datawookie.netlify.com/blog/2017/04/clustering-time-series-data/ for examples of how to use the TSclust package in R to cluster time series. The package itself is described in the article https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v062i01/v62i01.pdf. The package dtwclust will help you compare the performance of different time series clustering algorithms applied to the same data: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dtwclust/vignettes/dtwclust.pdf.

Comment: This document might prove useful too - it provides an overview of different time series clustering algorithms: https://beta.vu.nl/nl/Images/stageverslag-roelofsen_tcm235-882304.pdf.

Comment: Thank you so much for the informative documents and samples! I have some further questions if you won't mind: 1) If I would like to cluster the data(trend, change, etc in this context) by k-means or hierarchical clustering or cosine distance, generally speaking, I should transform the data to get some features like mean, standard deviation, variance, max, and min etc., correct? 2)On the other hand, the DTW(Dynamic Time Warping) gives a measure of 'distance between 2 lines across the time', then cluster the data based on the measure, correct?